# HTML input text glitch

Tags: html, input

When I paste text with multiple lines into my `<input type="text">` this happens:

[image: Input Text]

The the text normally stays in one line in the middle when I paste it onto another website:

[image: Input Text]

My CSS :

```
.textbox {
    padding:0 5px;
    height:30px;
    background:#FDFDFD;
    line-height:28px;
    width:250px;
    border:1px solid #D2D2D2;
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .textbox { line-height:13px; }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="textbox">
```

I am just curious on why this happens. I do not use `<input type="text">` for this purpose.

Comment: We need to see some code in order to help.

Comment: I am updating it now ...

Comment: Which browser is this happening in as I'm not seeing it in Chrome 22

Comment: My browser is Chrome 21.0.1180.83

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - I forgot to include a css style .... updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t do it. `<input type="text">` is for single-line input. In authoring, use `textarea` to allow multiple lines.

Comment: I am not trying to use this for multiple line inputs. I am just curious because when I paste it into a input from other websites, it the text doesn't glitch like this does.

Comment: You wrote “When I paste text with multiple lines”.

Comment: Yes. I am saying that when I paste text with multiple lines, this happens. However, I do not use it for that purpose. I am just curious about why that happens on my inputs and not on other websites.